# how to throw a message in activiti

Tags: events, activiti, event-triggers

I want to throw and catch intermediate message catch event in activiti. But I don't know how to implement it. The following is my bpmn where I link between web service with other human talks by intermediate message event.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
      <message id="msg" name="msg"></message>
      <process id="process" isExecutable="true">
        <startEvent id="start" name="start" activiti:initiator="initiator"></startEvent>
        <serviceTask id="upload" name="upload project" activiti:exclusive="false" activiti:class="fitman.services.MyAuthUser_WS"></serviceTask>
        <userTask id="provide" name="provide project details" activiti:assignee="${initiator}">
          <extensionElements>
            <activiti:formProperty id="user" name="user" type="user" required="true"></activiti:formProperty>
            <activiti:formProperty id="name" name="name" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
            <activiti:formProperty id="toAddress" name="toAddress" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
            <activiti:formProperty id="subject" name="subject" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
            <activiti:formProperty id="textBody" name="textBody" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
          </extensionElements>
        </userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-8D423749-D7C6-4617-843B-FC4B62CC2E0A" sourceRef="start" targetRef="provide"></sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-50642463-711F-4AD0-ABFC-F1A383392D4D" sourceRef="provide" targetRef="upload"></sequenceFlow>
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-9611F0F0-6CC0-4F56-8A7B-35624A0BB2D2" sourceRef="upload" targetRef="msg1"></sequenceFlow>
        <userTask id="validate" name="validate" activiti:assignee="msg1"></userTask>
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-B4044992-C9F3-47C8-A206-99CABAC46B6D" sourceRef="msg1" targetRef="validate"></sequenceFlow>
        <endEvent id="end"></endEvent>
        <sequenceFlow id="sid-163DD9FE-3708-4A6B-85FC-EB1E2354182B" sourceRef="validate" targetRef="end"></sequenceFlow>
        <intermediateCatchEvent id="msg1" name="msg1">
          <messageEventDefinition messageRef="msg"></messageEventDefinition>
        </intermediateCatchEvent>
      </process>

    </definitions>
```

What I am doing wrong or any idea how to implement it.

Now I am using signal, but still unable to start other user task after catching it; What I am doing wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/processdef">
  <signal id="newMsg" name="newMsg"></signal>
  <process id="model1" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="start" activiti:initiator="initiator"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="task1" name="task1" activiti:assignee="${initiator}">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="a" name="a" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-16842953-EA94-42A2-B116-C68A98C85090" sourceRef="start" targetRef="task1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-E2E35140-E272-4D5C-88A1-CD1039E6672B" sourceRef="task1" targetRef="serv1"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-9E02B791-B3C0-4B62-81BB-DA10424469DF" sourceRef="serv1" targetRef="s1"></sequenceFlow>
    <intermediateCatchEvent id="s1" name="s1">
      <signalEventDefinition signalRef="newMsg"></signalEventDefinition>
    </intermediateCatchEvent>
    <userTask id="task2" name="task2" activiti:assignee="s1">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="prenom" name="prenom" type="string"></activiti:formProperty>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="fitman.services.MyTaskListener"></activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-BC7E1EC1-6839-4440-A123-4127C00FAAA3" sourceRef="s1" targetRef="task2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-5A09EDC9-7B1F-4BAD-8D3B-DEB53A01768A" sourceRef="task2" targetRef="serv2"></sequenceFlow>
    <sequenceFlow id="sid-1DCF980A-AB99-4839-A5BA-8900A1AA0D51" sourceRef="serv2" targetRef="end"></sequenceFlow>
    <serviceTask id="serv1" name="serv1" activiti:class="fitman.services.MyAuthUser_WS"></serviceTask>
    <serviceTask id="serv2" name="serv2" activiti:class="fitman.services.MyAuthUser_WS"></serviceTask>
    <endEvent id="end" name="end"></endEvent>
  </process>

</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you use a signal event rather than a message event unless the event is coming from outside the BPMN environment. Signal events can be both emitted and caught from within a process instance where regular message events require a handler be configured within the application infrastructure.

If a tre message event is required, then you should consider looking into the camel task module as this allows you to both send and receive messages from a number of source/targets.

Comment: I did that with signal but yet no able to trigger anther user task after catching intermediate signal catcher.

Comment: Can you explain me that user task2 what should be the value of assignee ?? name="task2" activiti:assignee="s1"